# Couldn't click a button in a webpage when using puppeteer in node js

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

[image]

When I run and click a few buttons in a webpage it works and at one point there is a slide bar and when I try to click a button there using the same method it is not working. Please help

My code for other button click :

```
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('variable-item button-variable-item button')[0].click());
```

but the same method is not working if I try on a button which is in the slide bar of the main html page.

Comment: try `await page.evaluate("document.getElementsByClassName('variable-item button-variable-item button')[0].click()");` ?

Comment: it is not working . it is giving the error Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined . I am totally new in this and is there any chance a normal evaluate is not working because of the fact that the button is in the slide bar of my page ?

Comment: it's saying that `document.getElementsByClassName('variable-item button-variable-item button')[0]` is non-existent.. so try `console.log(await page.evaluate("document.getElementsByClassName('variable-item button-variable-item button'))` and see what is logged on the console

Comment: it think there is nothing logged only I can see {} . I couldn't access the button because of the fact that it is in the sliding window ? of my main html page ?

Comment: could be hmm.. pls update ur answer with a pic of what u mean cuz im not fully clear on it

Comment: Hello can you please share mail id or any ? I can share screen ?

Comment: no as in update ur question lawl.. upload image on the question

Comment: I have added the image please check .and help if possible . Is the pic ok to get the issue  ?

Comment: ok.. i think you would need to activate the slider because I assume the button is generated when the slide button is clicked

Comment: yes may be that is the reason . How can I do that ? Can you please let me know if you have any snippet ? or any pages I can read about activation ? but when I click the button the slider comes doesn't that means it is activated ?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct CSS class names within your evaluate? Do you get any errors on the Node console? Have you tried `await page.click('.variable-item.button-variable-item.button');`?

Comment: nope it is not working and I think it is due to the fact the button is on the slide which is on the main page . When I console log it it is only giving {} while the other buttons on the screen gave values .Any ideas how this can be solved ?

Comment: Based on your screenshot the element is in the DOM so a click should work on it. What could be: you need to wait for the element to be rendered with a `await page.waitForSelector('.variable-item.button-variable-item.button');` before applying the click.

Comment: You may need to share a bigger chunk of your script so we can see if the flow of the scraper should be optimized. `{}` means the element is not available (yet).